# Eclipse doesn't see class/package in import

Tags: java, eclipse

I use eclipse.

my problem description:

In import I see red underlyed  strings. But if I navigate - I see source code.

How does it dispay?

[image]

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: First organize your imports by pressing "ctrl+shift+o".. Next show us what happened after you pressed ctrl+shift+o.

Answer (score 2):

You must adjust the project's build path, so it contains the missing packages.

**Long answer**
You may navigate every class that is known to the workspace. But if they are underlined it means they are not available when building the project.

Click on the node "Referenced Libraries" to see what's included. If your imported package JAR is not listed there, adjust the build path.

Comment: When you build from cmd, what your -cp looks like? Where is ProductHelperServiceImpl defined?

Comment: I have complex ant tasks for building

Comment: The project settings in eclipse should reflect the very same setup that is used in ant. What happens, when you press ctrl+shift+o, as @TheListMind suggested?

Comment: OK. Now adjust your build path in project's settings so that it includes the JAR or project that defines the missing class.

Comment: likewise  Basilevs advice? I attempted

Comment: No, if it did not work. How many projects contain your workspace? Which project contains ProductHelperServiceImpl, and which project contains the error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45926/discussion-between-gstackoverflow-and-michael)

Comment: OK. I'll repeat it one more time: You *must* adjust your project's build path. The missing class is defined in another project, which your failing project does not know. If you don't know how to do so, take a look into the Eclipse manual. Hint: Right-click on project -> Project Settings -> Build Path -> Projects. Or, if you don't know or even don't want to know how to use Eclipse, don't use it. It won't help you.

Comment: *The missing class is defined in another project* - it is false. missing class define at the same project.

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting information. What is the concrete error message, when you try import the class again? Sorry, I should have asked this question first.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the folder containing "com/epam/dentsply/service" and choose "Build Path/Use as Source Folder". Be sure to select the one directly containing the "com" directory with your java files.

Comment: I made it. But I see old result